# Do I need a China Visa for Taiwan China Japan flights booked on different airlines?

Tags: visas, japan, us-citizens, china, taiwan

We are American and flying this route:

1. USA > TPE
2. TPE > PEK
3. PEK > KIX (5 days in Beijing)
4. Train to Tokyo
5. NRT > USA

1 and 2 are on Airline A, 3 is on Airline B, 5 is on Airline C.

**I am assuming airlines don't matter, only the Chinese cities, so does this qualify for 144 hour visa?**

Source: https://www.travelchinaguide.com/tour/visa/free-transit-144-hours.htm

Related: [What does 'Confirmed Seat' mean with regards to Beijing 144-hour visa-free transit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123912/what-does-confirmed-seat-mean-with-regards-to-beijing-144-hour-visa-free-trans)

Update: tldr - Yes it qualifies but still needs a *temporary entry permit which is called a visa in Chinese*. More details below.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answeer is yes. But I'll leave the authoritative answer to others.

Comment: Any authoritative answers? Thanks @xuq01

Comment: I hope I could give a more authoritative answer, but this is not something I'm super knowledgeable about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Recently I tried to go through foreigner line at customs at PEK.

Officer said you need a permit for any stay in China if leaving airport. **My itinerary counts for a “visa free 144 hour stay” but that still requires a permit that you can get at a consulate in your home country or at visa/permit counter in airport.**

I took this photo at PEK.

[image: this is the visa/permit counter]

Comment: Could you explain what information you found to lead you to this conclusion (links to embassy websites, etc)?  We would like your answer to be useful to future users, and I don't think that they would want to rely on a random person's word.  The more so because your answer is counterintuitive - you need a visa for visa free travel?

Comment: @NateEldredge understand. this happened to me recently so added more details and photo

Comment: @Paddez It seems pretty obvious to me. You go to this desk and fill out the application form, and then you go to immigration.